# Autofill cells down

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to basically drag and drop, adding a row as needed.

This inserts entire rows rather than moving down.

It is a dynamic entry. Sometimes it will be 2 rows some others will be 100+.

```vb
ActiveSheet.Range("A15:AB15").Select
Selection.FillDown
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = 0
    Selection.FillDown
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
Loop
```

I need the loop to drag and drop some formulas I have on a row above then insert a new, drag and drop again and continue until it meets the value 0.

Comment: Could you explain, what you want to achieve. I suppose that you don't need `selection` and `filldown` at all but could write directly to the range.

Comment: Do you have a mock-up of your data?  Can you show the below/after for the mock-up?  More detail is needed for your question to be answered appropriately.

Comment: Hi @Ike from column A to column AB I have on each cell a formula that refers to another sheet that has the data. The formula is something like this ='Make'!A12. What I manually do is select the whole range and drag and drop filling out what refers to the data on the sheet "Make" then I proceed to delete the empty cells (in this case the cells go to the value 0). Probably I do not need the select but I am not sure how to accomplish this without it

Comment: Hi @Cyril is a bit tricky to get the actual data as there is a formula in each cell that picks up data from other sheets. What I am trying to accomplish is that let's say on sheet "make" I have 100 rows of data. Then I go to my other sheet that selects specific cells from "makup" and I drag and drop the formula on my "summary" sheet.

Values changes depending on the item so is not something that is always constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to try to answer the question I think you are asking and you can offer clarification if I have misunderstood.  Let's suppose you have the following two worksheets in a workbook.

[image]

Sheet "Data" has inventory levels for given dates.  The values in Columns B through D of that sheet start at some number and eventually reach zero as we move down the column.

On the sheet named Summary, you have a a row of formula that refer to the cells atop the list of values and you want to copy that formula down until the value of the formula copied in each column is equal to 0.

Here is a VBA macro that will do that:

```
Sub copy_all_down_to_zero()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Summary").Range("b2:d2")
        copy_formula_down_to_zero cell
    Next
End Sub


Sub copy_formula_down_to_zero(cell As Range)
    Do Until cell.Value <= 0

        ' this line added in response to comment below
        If Len(cell.Offset(1).Value) > 0 Then cell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert

        cell.Offset(1).Formula2R1C1 = cell.Formula2R1C1
        Set cell = cell.Offset(1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Just configure "copy_all_down_to_zero" to refer to range that holds the initial formulas and run it.

Comment: Wow! Yes, it does what I need apart from that I have some data at the bottom on the summary sheet so it will need to add 1 entire row as it will override the data that I have below. Thank you very much for providing the code!

Comment: Would you be able to let me know how to add an entire row after it finishes on row 2?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "after it finishes on row 2"

Comment: The code does column A row 2 then moves to row 3 and 4, then meets 0 and jumps to column B and repeats. However I have data at the bottom of row 3. The codes currently overrides the data that I have in column A to AB row 3. Would it be possible for the code to add an entire row so it does not overrides the data? I tried doing it myself by modifying your code but I can't work it out. Thanks again!

Comment: Let's continue this conversation in a chat room:  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243495/gove-and-santil

Comment: @Santil if this resolved the question as described *in your post*, please mark as Answered.

Comment: @Gove Hiya, I cannot make a comment in the chat as I am new to stackoverflow. I need to have more than 20 reputation. But basically what you sent me over the chat, yes I have some data at the bottom of what I need to fill in and it does not have to be deleted.

Comment: ok.  I've added a new line that will insert a row when there is already data in the cell that is about to get the new formula.

Comment: @Gove thank you very much for the code it does what I need now!! You are a legend!